# MassTransit and SNS/SQS in multi-environment and multi-instance scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

I am relatively new to MassTransit in .NET and its integration with AWS SNS/SQS. The documentation and tutorials are fine, but as usual, the devil is in the details.

I am especially unsure on what the best way would be to configure MassTransit in an environment with multiple envs, e.g., development, staging, production, and multiple application instances in production environment.

[Multi-environment sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvd6L.png)

Here is what I know so far:

- For different environments, create a dedicated SNS topic for each message and each environment, e.g., `development-my-event` and `production-my-event`.
- Endpoints need to  be unique. Therefore, create a separate endpoint for each consumer in the application, e.g., `development-consumer1-my-event`. A second consumer in a different application will get an endpoint `development-consumer2-my-event`.

1. Now assuming that there are multiple people working simultaneously on the applications, in order to avoid messaging conflicts, they will need their own topics and queues as well, e.g., `development-user123-my-event`. Is that a valid way to go?
2. The production code runs in a clustered environment, i.e., there will be multiple instances of any application. Do we have to make the endpoints of each applications then even more unique, like, addings another identifier so that the queue names do not conflict?
3. Hoping that this is not the case, I would assume that I can start many identical consumers that listen to the same endpoint, which would (hopefully) also solve that I would only one of those to process e.g. a command message.

Any insights to my thoughts highly appreciated, thanks!

So far:

- Implemented custom entity and endpoint name formatters to distinguish different environments.
- Formatter diversy further for different dev machines
- Specified to use ".fifo" for command queues and topics

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144060/how-do-i-separate-out-sqs-queues-for-different-environments-in-mass-transit

Comment: Hi Chris, regarding the env-separation, I agree. But I don't feel like any of questions 1/2/3 are answered.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you'd need to add yet another discriminator for each developer. Not sure I would ever do this, I'd likely just use `localstack` and develop locally.
2. If by multiple instances, you mean scaled out to load balance by competing consumer on the same queue, that's the default behavior. If you need to fan out events to the same consumer in multiple applications, you'll need to either scope them or use some prefix on the endpoint name formatter.
3. As mentioned above, competing consumer is the default if a service is scaled out to multiple instances.